# How can I get click on collider relative in percentages or local points

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a plane with MeshCollider and I managed when I clicked on that plane to create new box on that position with code:

```
    bool hit = GetComponent<MeshCollider> ().Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition), out hitInfo, 1000.0f);
    if (hit) {
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.position = hitInfo.point;
    }
```

That plane represents a football playground ( in real life it would be 100 x 50 meters ). How can I get relative where I clicked to plane ?
Whole Image represents Plane ( football playground 100 m x 50 m ) and P areas where when I clicked I play Penal.
( I want to know if it is clicked inside some area I would play penal, for example: if I touched between 0 and 16 meters or between 84 and 100 meters )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple, add two game object with no renderer but with collider. Place them a bit above the main plane so they catch the raycast. Then check which you are hitting.

```
bool hit = GetComponent<MeshCollider> ().Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition), out hitInfo, 1000.0f);
if (hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Field")) {
    GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    cube.transform.position = hitInfo.point;
} else if(hit.gameObject.CompareTag("PenaltyZone")){}
```

Comment: Thanks but If I received areas from server, want to have more or dimensions I received from server ? I need coordinates in meters (relative to 100 x 50 ) , not in world unity coordinate.

Comment: Either make field in Unity of 100x50 or take the position, divide by the actual length of the object and multiply by 100 or 50 (x,y).